# How to add StructuredServiceItem in Google my business location using java?

Tags: java, google-my-business-api, google-my-business, google-business-profile-api, google-business-profile

**Introduction:**
If you know what is Business Profile on Google so please skip introduction part.

As I have received notification for this question that this question needs more clarifications, I can explain a little more about what are the services, google categories and attributes of a location, [here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/locations). However, the link I have provided is very obvious and who works on `Google My business` or the newer version which is called `Google Business Profile` has a very clear idea of what I am talking.

"With a Business Profile on Google, you can manage how your local business shows up across Google products, like Maps and Search. If you run a business that serves customers at a particular location, or you serve customers within a designated service area, your Business Profile can help people find you. Verified businesses on Google are twice as likely to be considered reputable.[Business Profile on Google](https://support.google.com/business/answer/6300665?hl=en)".

a location is described [Location GBP Documentation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations), and contains main information about this location such as opening hours, phone  number, email, categories etc., that some are obligatory and some of them are optional. My question is on `serviceItems` which is optional.
the question is how to create it using `JAVA`.
[image]

**My Question:**

Using [The GMB documentation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations#Location.ServiceItem) ,I am trying to define a service for my location in JAVA.
I can add a `FreeFormServiceItem` service but not `StructuredServiceItem`.
I have defined an enum for servicesTypes:

```
enum serviceTypes{
            BOOL,
            URL,
            REPEATED_ENUM,
            ENUM
        }
     JsonObject jsonUpdate = new JsonObject();
     JsonArray serviceItems = new JsonArray();
      String description = "something";
      serviceTypes serviceTypeId = serviceTypes.BOOL;  
     serviceItems.add(structuredServiceItem(serviceTypeId, description));
      jsonUpdate.add("serviceItems", serviceItems);

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            String url = "https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/" + locationName + "?updateMask=" + updateMask + "&validateOnly=" + validateOnly;
            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, jsonUpdate.toString());

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .patch(body)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)
                    .build();

            try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
                System.out.println("Response status code: " + response.code());
                System.out.println("Response body: " + response.body().string());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and then the **structuredServiceItem** :

```
 private static JsonObject structuredServiceItem(serviceTypes serviceTypeId, String description) {
            JsonObject structuredServiceItem = new JsonObject();
            structuredServiceItem.addProperty("serviceTypeId", serviceTypeId.toString()); 
            structuredServiceItem.addProperty("description", description);

            return structuredServiceItem;
        }
```

The error is

```
 Response body: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"serviceTypeId\" at 'location.service_items[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"description\" at 'location.service_items[0]': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "location.service_items[0]",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"serviceTypeId\" at 'location.service_items[0]': Cannot find field."
          },
          {
            "field": "location.service_items[0]",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"description\" at 'location.service_items[0]': Cannot find field."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the response. The problem was that I was defining serviceTypes incorrectly. By fetching `Google Categories`, it is possible to obtain the required information for defining `StructuredServiceItem`.

Supposing that the variable **mybusinessCategories** takes care of credentials and also initials the API.

```
    MyBusinessBusinessInformation.Categories.List requestEn=mybusinessCategories.categories().list().setView("FULL").
            setLanguageCode("your languageCode").setRegionCode("your regionCode").setPageSize(100);
    ListCategoriesResponse ResponseEn=requestEn.execute();
    List<Category> categoriesEn=ResponseEn.getCategories();
    while (ResponseEn.getNextPageToken() != null) {
        requestEn.setPageToken(ResponseEn.getNextPageToken());
        ResponseEn=requestEn.execute();
        categoriesEn.addAll(ResponseEn.getCategories());    
    }

    for(Category cEn:categoriesEn) {
        if(cEn.containsKey("serviceTypes")) {  
            List<ServiceType> servicesEn =vcEn.getServiceTypes();
            for( ServiceType s: servicesEn) {
                System.out.println( cEn.getName());
                System.out.println(s.getServiceTypeId());
                System.out.println( s.getDisplayName());

            }
        }
```